# MVC 3 Application on Server always gives 500 error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, .net-4.0

I am bin deploying a MVC 3 site... it works fine on our 'Staging' server, which "theoretically" mirrors our "QA" server. However, when deployed to QA, it just gives a 500 error when trying to access it from the web browser. We've turned detailed errors on in the web.config, turning off friendly http errors in IE, but nothing.

Any suggestions on what we might check for? I've already verified that .NET 4 Client & .NET 4 Extended are installed on the server. I need to compile a checklist of possibilities. Scratching my head hard on this one...

UPDATE:

I noticed one oddity here, running the powershell command:

```
test-path "$<Env:ProgramFiles(x86)>\Microsoft ASP.NET"
```

returns false. As I said before, .NET 4 (Client & Extended) are installed, but nothing else. I find this a little suspect...

Comment: Open the website from the server desktop perhaps, if possible. Not sure why you get 500's when you turned on detailed errors.

Comment: Are you seeing ASP.NET error pages (Yellow Screen Of Death) or IIS error pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the server's desktop and open the web-site from the browser there.  You should then see the actual exception details.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to take some troubleshooting on your part.

But, I would check the following, it sounds like it involves one of these guys:

- web.config
- machine.config
- make sure all .dlls are installed (check the GAC)
- make sure your IIS pool isn't wrong version

These are only a few off the top of my head.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Andrew, knowing the exception would really help.

Just to make sure, you've tried setting the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) element in your web.config to *Off* right? This way the exception details will show everywhere instead of a HTTP 500.

Try changing the AppPool that your site uses is set to **.NET 4 Integrated**

You could also try running [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) to re-register .NET with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like customErrors and httpErrors setting issue. Also check IIS permission/trust levels are configured properly.